# cannot convert json array to string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, arrays

I am not getting any response from server with following code ,I am getting token error '<' i have tried all

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"url", 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output) {
            var asd = JSON.stringify(output)
            var i = $.parseJSON(asd);
            for(var j=0;j<i.length;j++) {
                $('#one').append('<p><div>TITLE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href='+i[j].links+'>'+i[j].Title+'</a><br>SOURCE&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :  &nbsp; &nbsp;'+i[j].Source+'<br>CATEGORY&nbsp;: &nbsp; &nbsp;'+i[j].Category+'<hr></p></div>');
                //$('#one').append('<p><div style="background-color:#ccc"><span style="font-weight:bold" >SOURCE</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :  &nbsp; &nbsp;'+i[j].Source+'<p>');
                //$('#one').append('<p><div style="background-color:#ccc" onclick="get"><span style="font-weight:bold" >CATEGORY</span> &nbsp;: &nbsp; &nbsp;'+i[j].Category+'<hr><p></div>');

            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call JSON.stringify() and parseJSON(). If output is an array, you can use directly output[0].Source and output[0].Category

```
$.ajax({
url:"url", 
dataType: 'json' ,

success:function(output) {
    for(var j=0;j<output.length;j++) {
        $('#one').append('<p><div>TITLE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp: &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href='+output[j].links+'>'+output[j].Title+'</a><br>SOURCE&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :  &nbsp; &nbsp;'+output[j].Source+'<br>CATEGORY&nbsp;: &nbsp; &nbsp;'+output[j].Category+'<hr></p></div>');
    }
},
error:function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError){
    alert(xhr.statusText);
    alert(thrownError);
}
});
```

Comment: it returns unexpected token < in alert box

Comment: @user2992174 can you post raw response from server here?

Comment: syntax Error:Unexpected token <

Comment: @user2992174 ok, I sent this request by myself. Server also anwers some commentaries at the end of data: <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code --> You should remove this

Comment: @user2992174 Server should not answer any comments, only data